# Bootstrap Dual Vertical Navbar Work Simultaniously

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I M Using two vertical navbar in both left and right side in my website 
when i switch to mobile view navbar collapse and when i click on one navbar to expand, both menu expands

I want to expand one navbar at a time

Please tell a suitable solution

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"     Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link href="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="Style/StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="Header">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-2 HeadLeft">
                    STATUS 99
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2 HeadRight">
                    <ul class="list-inline">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">FB Scrap</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">SMS</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 LeftMenu">
                <h4>FB Status Categories</h4>
                <div class="sidebar-nav">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <span class="visible-xs navbar-brand">Sidebar menu</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Reviews <span class="badge">1,118</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-push-8 RightMenu">
                <h4>FB Cover pictures</h4>
                <div class="sidebar-nav">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>
                            <span class="visible-xs navbar-brand">Sidebar menu</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse sidebar-navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active"><a href="#">Menu Item 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Menu Item 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Reviews <span class="badge">1,118</span></a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-pull-2">
                <h1>Main Content</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
font-family:Tahoma;
}

.Header{
background-color:rgb(59,89,152);
min-height:3em;
color:white;
}

.HeadLeft{
font-family:'Times New Roman';
font-size:2.2em;
padding:0.1em;
}

.HeadRight{
font-family:Tahoma;
font-size:1.25em;
padding:0.1em;

}

.HeadRight a{
text-decoration:none;
color:rgb(255,255, 255);    
}

.LeftMenu{
box-shadow: 0 0.6250em 0.3125em #888888;
}

.LeftMenu h4{
background-color:rgb(240, 240, 240);
/*padding:0.1em 0;*/
}

.RightMenu{
box-shadow: 0 0.6250em 0.3125em #888888;
}

.RightMenu h4{
background-color:rgb(240, 240, 240);
/*padding:0.1em 0;*/
}

ul li{
/*padding:0.2em;*/
}

/* make sidebar nav vertical */ 
@media (min-width: 768px) {
.sidebar-nav .navbar .navbar-collapse {
padding: 0;
max-height: none;
}
.sidebar-nav .navbar ul {
float: none;
display: block;
}
.sidebar-nav .navbar li {
float: none;
display: block;
}
.sidebar-nav .navbar li a {
padding-top: 12px;
padding-bottom: 12px;
}
}
```

Comment: "_Please tell a suitable solution_", with all respect - solution to what?

Comment: Please provide a fiddle or paste some code you have used.

Comment: would really need to see some code, but my guess would be change the data-target to point to the left or right navbar. http://www.bootply.com/uLHXbC6AvB